Breaststroke swimming - breathing cadence does not match stroking rhythm
I'm a rather short guy (5'3", 1.60m) so my arms are accordingly short. This leads to a rather quick stroking rhythm compared to my comfortable breathing cadence (and the stroking rhythm of other, taller people who seem to match their stroking and breathing rhythms better than I do) when doing breaststroke swimming. This forces me to keep my head always above the water level instead of me exhaling with my head in the water.
How can I improve this? What would be the best way?

One option is to lengthen you glide portion. Another is to work on getting more power on your pull stroke, which will lengthen it. Watch videos of good breaststrokers and watch how their hands move. Otherwise, match your breathing to your stroke to maintain good form (perhaps breathe in less so you can get it out faster).
